# I'm confused as to why "| true" in a makefile has the same effect as "|| true"

Tags: shell, pipe

I have a makefile where I'm stopping a service before removing a file. When it couldn't stop the service, it would break on error. This is clearly unwanted so I thought I'd add `|| true` but missed a `|`. Making it:

```
stop service foo | true
rm /etc/init/foo.conf
```

I'm confused as to why this is working and what is happening. Does this mean that `true` is an application and not merely a keyword? Are they the same? Is there a good reason to use `| true`?

Comment: The commands make little sense as the exit code of `true` is being ignored. The only side-effect is that `stdout` is redirected to nowhere in an unreliable way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`true` and `false` are [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (also typically shell built-ins) that just return 0 and non-0, for situations where you happen to need that behavior. From the man pages:

> true - do nothing, successfully
>   false - do nothing, unsuccessfully

So you're piping the output from `stop service foo` into `true`, which ignores it and returns 0. Technically it works, but you should probably use `|| true` so it's obvious what your intention was; there's really no reason to pipe output into a program that's not using it

Comment: Makes perfect sense. :) I don't know why but reading *"do nothing, unsuccessfully."* makes me laugh.

Comment: Another reason to avoid `| true` is that if the command produced enough output to fill up the pipe buffer, it would block waiting for `true` to read it.

Comment: @cjm or die due to SIGPIPE

Comment: @Kit: Note that `foo || true` and `foo | true` won't do the same thing: `foo || true` will show the output from `foo`, whereas `foo | true` will discard everything `foo` writes to its standard output (and `foo` is likely to die with `SIGPIPE` or block, as already indicated).

Comment: This answer is perfect except for the word "probably"...!