# How big is the pipe buffer?

Tags: pipe, buffer

As a comment in [I'm confused as to why "| true" in a makefile has the same effect as "|| true"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/im-confused-as-to-why-true-in-a-makefile-has-the-same-effect-as-true/11938#11938) user [cjm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2421/cjm) wrote:

> Another reason to avoid `| true` is that if the command produced enough output to fill up the pipe buffer, it would block waiting for true to read it.

Do we have some way of finding out what the size of the pipe buffer is?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The capacity of a pipe buffer varies across systems (and can even vary on the same system). I am not sure if there is a quick, easy, and cross-platform way to just lookup the capacity of a pipe.

Mac OS X, for example, uses a capacity of 16384 bytes by default, but can switch to 65336 byte capacities if large write are made to the pipe, or will switch to a capacity of a single system page if too much kernel memory is already being used by pipe buffers (see [`xnu/bsd/sys/pipe.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.9.37/bsd/sys/pipe.h), and [`xnu/bsd/kern/sys_pipe.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.9.37/bsd/kern/sys_pipe.c); since these are from FreeBSD, the same behavior may happen there, too).

One Linux [*pipe(7)* man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) says that pipe capacity is 65536 bytes since Linux 2.6.11 and a single system page prior to that (e.g. 4096 bytes on (32-bit) x86 systems). The code ([`include/linux/pipe_fs_i.h`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/pipe_fs_i.h;h=77257c92155aa4efb6ea68d9c99298426aedc60b;hb=HEAD), and [`fs/pipe.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/pipe.c;h=da42f7db50de42640a7fa56df21e21bbb48cf588;hb=HEAD)) seems to use 16 system pages (i.e. 64 KiB if a system page is 4 KiB), but the buffer for each pipe can be adjusted via a *fcntl* on the pipe (up to a maximum capacity which defaults to 1048576 bytes, but can be changed via `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`)).

---

Here is a little *bash*/*perl* combination that I used to test the pipe capacity on my system:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
test $# -ge 1 || { echo "usage: $0 write-size [wait-time]"; exit 1; }
test $# -ge 2 || set -- "$@" 1
bytes_written=$(
{
    exec 3>&1
    {
        perl -e '
            $size = $ARGV[0];
            $block = q(a) x $size;
            $num_written = 0;
            sub report { print STDERR $num_written * $size, qq(\n); }
            report; while (defined syswrite STDOUT, $block) {
                $num_written++; report;
            }
        ' "$1" 2>&3
    } | (sleep "$2"; exec 0<&-);
} | tail -1
)
printf "write size: %10d; bytes successfully before error: %d\n" \
    "$1" "$bytes_written"
```

Here is what I found running it with various write sizes on a Mac OS X 10.6.7 system (note the change for writes larger than 16KiB):

```
% /bin/bash -c 'for p in {0..18}; do /tmp/ts.sh $((2 ** $p)) 0.5; done'
write size:          1; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:          2; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:          4; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:          8; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:         16; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:         32; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:         64; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:        128; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:        256; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:        512; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:       1024; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:       2048; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:       4096; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:       8192; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:      16384; bytes successfully before error: 16384
write size:      32768; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      65536; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:     131072; bytes successfully before error: 0
write size:     262144; bytes successfully before error: 0
```

The same script on Linux 3.19:

```
/bin/bash -c 'for p in {0..18}; do /tmp/ts.sh $((2 ** $p)) 0.5; done'
write size:          1; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:          2; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:          4; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:          8; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:         16; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:         32; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:         64; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:        128; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:        256; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:        512; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       1024; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       2048; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       4096; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       8192; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      16384; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      32768; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      65536; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:     131072; bytes successfully before error: 0
write size:     262144; bytes successfully before error: 0
```

---

Note: The `PIPE_BUF` value defined in the C header files (and the *pathconf* value for `_PC_PIPE_BUF`), does not specify the capacity of pipes, but the maximum number of bytes that can be written atomically (see [POSIX *write(2)*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html#tag_03_866)).

Quote from [`include/linux/pipe_fs_i.h`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/pipe_fs_i.h;h=77257c92155aa4efb6ea68d9c99298426aedc60b;hb=HEAD#l134):

```
/* Differs from PIPE_BUF in that PIPE_SIZE is the length of the actual
   memory allocation, whereas PIPE_BUF makes atomicity guarantees.  */
```

Comment: Great answer.  Especially for the link to POSIX write(2), which says: *The effective size of a pipe or FIFO (the maximum amount that can be written in one operation without blocking) may vary dynamically, depending on the implementation, so it is not possible to specify a fixed value for it.*

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `fcntl()` on Linux; I had spent a while looking for userspace buffering programs because I thought the built-in pipes didn't have a large enough buffer. Now I see that they do, if I have CAP_SYS_RESOURCE or root is willing to expand the maximum pipe size. As what I want will only be run on a specific Linux computer (mine), this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you please explain the basic idea of your script? I am staring at it and I cannot figure out how it works? Especially what is the purpose using curly brackets here VAR=$({})? Thank you.

Comment: @WakanTanka: It is a bit much to describe in a comment, but that particular construct is a [parameter assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) (`var=…`) of the output of a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (`$(…)`) that includes [grouped commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) (`{…}`, and `(…)`). It also uses several (less common) [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (i.e. `0<&-` and `3>&1`).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen thank you for explaining syntax, can you please simply describe the main idea?

Comment: @WakanTanka: The Perl program writes to its stdout (a shell-created pipe—the one that is being tested) in blocks of a given size and reports to its stderr a running total of how much it has written (until it gets an error—usually because the pipe’s buffer is full or possibly because the reading end of the pipe has been closed after a short time (`exec 0<&-`)). The final report is collected (`tail -1`) and printed along with the write size.

Comment: Is it possible for a process to write to the named pipe (that has no readers) a piece of data that is smaller than the pipe buffer size, and just exit straight away? How does the blocking semantics of a named pipe determine when when a write has finished and allow the reader to read? What if a process write 1 kb, waited 10 seconds, wrote another 1kb without ever exiting? Does the reader get 1kb, then 1kb, or does it block until getting 2kb?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: That is probably too much to address in a comment. Perhaps ask it as a new question? You might find some answers in the POSIX spec: [FIFO definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_163), [open(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), [read(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), and [write(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) (search for FIFO in these later ones).

Comment: Great answer. I think there's a minor typo and that you probably meant `65536`, not `65336` for the big pipe size for mac. In the header file it's defined as `64*1024`, which is `65536`. `65536` is also what your empirical tests showed.

Answer (score 48):

this shell-line can show pipe buffer size too:

```
M=0; while true; do dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null; \
       M=$(($M+1)); echo -en "\r$M KB" 1>&2; done | sleep 999
```

(sending 1k chunks to blocked pipe until buffer full) ...some test outputs:

```
64K (intel-debian), 32K (aix-ppc), 64K (jslinux bellard.org)      ...Ctrl+C.
```

shortest bash-one-liner using printf:

```
M=0; while printf A; do >&2 printf "\r$((++M)) B"; done | sleep 999
```

Comment: Very nice! `(dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999) &` then wait a second and `killall -SIGUSR1 dd` gives `65536 bytes (66 kB) copied, 5.4987 s, 11.9 kB/s` - same as your solution, but at 1 byte resolution ;)

Comment: For the record, on Solaris 10/11 SPARC/x86 the `dd` command blocks at 16 KiB. On Fedora 23/25 x86-64, it blocks at 64 KiB.

Comment: @frostschutz: That's a nice simplification. Pragmatically, you could just run `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999` in the foreground, wait a second, then press `^C`. If you wanted a one-liner on Linux and BSD/macOS (more robust than using `killall`):
`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999 & sleep 1 && pkill -INT -P $$ -x dd`

Comment: For unwary users, this seems like an off-label use of `sleep` for creating a blocked pipe for a set amount of time (999s here). Before killing `dd`, `dd` progress can be monitored using USR1 signal (https://askubuntu.com/a/215521/134766). This will show the transfer stats frozen at pipe buffer size.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some further alternatives to explore the actual pipe buffer capacity using shell commands only:

```
# get pipe buffer size using Bash
yes produce_this_string_as_output | tee >(sleep 1) | wc -c

# portable version
( (sleep 1; exec yes produce_this_string_as_output) & echo $! ) | 
     (pid=$(head -1); sleep 2; kill "$pid"; wc -c </dev/stdin)

# get buffer size of named pipe
sh -c '
  rm -f fifo
  mkfifo fifo
  yes produce_this_string_as_output | tee fifo | wc -c &
  exec 3<&- 3<fifo
  sleep 1
  exec 3<&-
  rm -f fifo
'

# Mac OS X
#getconf PIPE_BUF /
#open -e /usr/include/limits.h /usr/include/sys/pipe.h
# PIPE_SIZE
# BIG_PIPE_SIZE
# SMALL_PIPE_SIZE
# PIPE_MINDIRECT
```

Comment: On Solaris 10, `getconf PIPE_BUF /` prints `5120` which matches the `ulimit -a | grep pipe` output but doesn't match the 16 KiB after which `dd .. | sleep ...` blocks.

Comment: On Fedora 25, your first `yes` method prints `73728` instead of the 64 KiB determined with `dd if=/dev/zero bs=4096  status=none | pv  -bn  | sleep 1`

Comment: I too get `73728` from `yes | tee >(sleep 1) | wc -c` instead of `65536`. I think this is because we measure the buffer of `>( )` instead of `|` even though both should use the same mechanism under the hood... strange. With `yes | tee >(wc -c >&2) | sleep 1` I get the correct number.

Answer (score 7):

This is a quick and dirty hack on Ubuntu 12.04, YMMV

```c
cat >pipesize.c

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include </usr/include/linux/fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
  int fd ;
  long pipesize ;

  if( argc>1 ){
  // if command line arg, associate a file descriptor with it
    fprintf( stderr, "sizing %s ... ", argv[1] );
    fd = open( argv[1], O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK );
  }else{
  // else use STDIN as the file descriptor
    fprintf( stderr, "sizing STDIN ... " );
    fd = 0 ;
  }

  fprintf( stderr, "%ld bytes\n", (long)fcntl( fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ ));
  if( errno )fprintf( stderr, "Uh oh, errno is %d\n", errno );
  if( fd )close( fd );
}

gcc -o pipesize pipesize.c

mkfifo /tmp/foo

./pipesize /tmp/foo

>sizing /tmp/foo ... 65536 bytes

date | ./pipesize

>sizing STDIN ... 65536 bytes
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need the value in Python>=3.3, here's a simple method (assuming you can run call out to `dd`):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired
p = Popen(["dd", "if=/dev/zero", "bs=1"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
try: 
    p.wait(timeout=1)
except TimeoutExpired: 
    p.kill()
    print(len(p.stdout.read()))
```

Answer (score 1):

For finding [mklement0's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer#comment600163_72827) more easily, I turned their comment into this answer:

> Pragmatically, you could just run `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999` in the foreground, wait a second, then press `^C` [= <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>].

> If you wanted a one-liner on Linux and BSD/macOS (more robust than using killall):
> `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 999 & sleep 1 && pkill -INT -P $$ -x dd`

With GNU `timeout` you can simplify this to ...

```
timeout -s INT 3 dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 | sleep 99
```

Either way, the output will be something like below.

```
65537+0 records in
65536+0 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB, 64 KiB) copied, 2.99738 s, 21.9 kB/s
```

In above example, my  buffer was 65536 bytes.
`dd` couldn't write the 6553**7**th byte, because the buffer was full.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/282382) adapted to `zsh`:

```bsh
#+begin_src bsh.dash :results verbatim :exports both :wrap example
test-buffer() {
    test $# -ge 1 || { echo "usage: $0 write-size [wait-time]"; return 1; }
    test $# -ge 2 || set -- "$@" 1
    bytes_written=$(
        {
            exec 3>&1
            {
                perl -e '
            $size = $ARGV[0];
            $block = q(a) x $size;
            $num_written = 0;
            sub report { print STDERR $num_written * $size, qq(\n); }
            report; while (defined syswrite STDOUT, $block) {
                $num_written++; report;
            }
        ' "$1" 2>&3
            } | (sleep "$2"; exec 0<&-);
        } | tail -1
                 )
    printf "write size: %10d; bytes successfully before error: %d\n" \
        "$1" "$bytes_written"
}
uname
for i in {1..18} ; do
    test-buffer $((2**i)) 1
done
#+end_src
```

Results:

```
#+begin_example
Darwin
write size:          2; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:          4; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:          8; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:         16; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:         32; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:         64; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:        128; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:        256; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:        512; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       1024; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       2048; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       4096; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:       8192; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      16384; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      32768; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:      65536; bytes successfully before error: 65536
write size:     131072; bytes successfully before error: 0
write size:     262144; bytes successfully before error: 0
#+end_example
```

Answer (score -1):

As simple as executing this:

```
echo "$(($(ulimit -p)*512)) bytes"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct, the value reported by `ulimit -p` is `PIPE_BUF` which is the largest size for which writes are guaranteed to be atomic. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625116/813810