# Replacing sshfs with ssh

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I love to do just this:

```
$ sshfs mountPoint myServer
$ cp thisFile mountPoint
```

I am now using LiveCD and I do not have sshfs utility available and I need run `$ sudo dd /dev/sdb2 > mountPoint`, how to do this as easy as with sshfs?

**Perhaps related**

1. https://superuser.com/questions/397646/cloning-fresh-windows-7-fsed-hdd-to-linux-server-because-having-no-external-hdd

**Comment to Psusi**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l|tail
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4864 cylinders, total 78142806 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x181d6d22

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     3074047    12288000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2         3074048   600563711  2389958656    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       600563712   625139711    98304000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
$ sudo file -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x7, active, starthead 32, startsector 2048, 3072000 sectors; partition 2: ID=0x7, starthead 89, startsector 3074048, 597489664 sectors; partition 3: ID=0x7, starthead 254, startsector 600563712, 24576000 sectors, code offset 0xe
$ sudo ntfsclone --save-image --output - /dev/sdb2
ntfsclone v2011.4.12AR.4 (libntfs-3g)
ERROR(22): Opening '/dev/sdb2' as NTFS failed: Invalid argument
Apparently device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't have a valid NTFS. Maybe you selected
the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g. /dev/hda, not /dev/hda1)?
```

Comment: FYI, if this is a windows partition you are trying to clone, use `ntfsclone` instead of `dd`.  It is smart enough to skip the trash in the unused/free sectors, and can compress the image.

Comment: @psusi: could you tell more in an answer? Yes, this is a w -partitition (actually the whole harddrive is from fresh w machine). I tried this `ntfsclone --save-image --output - /dev/sdb3 | bzip2 | ssh m@m.com 'cat > 15032012_w7_3.img.bz2'` but getting no content?!

Comment: Did you run ntfsclone as root ( sudo )?

Comment: @psusi: yes, look at the updated question. I get error 22 when trying to execute the command.

Comment: Looks like that partition either doesn't actually contain an ntfs filesystem or it is damaged.  What does `sudo blkid` say the type is?

Comment: @psusi: it finds only `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5`, nothing about `/dev/sdb.*`. `$ sudo fdisk -l` lists though `/dev/sdb.*` as shown above.

Comment: Try `sudo blkid -p /dev/sdb`

Comment: @psusi: nothing again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2793/discussion-between-psusi-and-hhh)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question directly

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 ibs=1M | ssh -C myServer 'dd of=/path/to/destination obs=1M'
```

For bonus you can do the following to see the progress (assuming you have the `pv` utility)

```
pv /dev/sdb2 | ssh -C myServer 'dd of=/path/to/destination obs=1M'
```

Comment: Bah, jofel beat me to it. Still leaving though as the answer is slightly different. Also invoking `pv` in the method I provided lets `pv` give you progress of how much is left (including time estimates), instead of just how much has transferred so far.

Comment: why `ibs=1M` and `obs=1M`?

Comment: Larger block sizes (over the default for `dd`) improve IO to/from physical volumes. While the the value jofel gave (64k) is probably fine, memory is cheap and I usually just set it at 1m.

Comment: @Patrick I've done some measurements. See my [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34247/help-me-to-replace-sshfs-with-ssh/34271#comment46573_34271) on my answer. I measure with `obs=1M` 1.8 GB/s, with  `obs=16k` 2.8 GB/s from /dev/zero to /dev/null over a pipe. But in our case the queue is usually not the limiting factor, so the discussion is just   theoretical...

Comment: @jofel piping to /dev/null is not a valid test. Its size of the blocks to/from the physical volume that matters.

Comment: @Patrick I wrote at the end of my comment, that the discussion is here just theoretical. The maximum speed over a pipe with `dd` does only matter if the possible throughput of the programs on both sides of the pipe is is higher than the throughput of the pipe. That could be the case if you read/write to ramdisks or SSDs. You cannot transfer more than 64k at once over a pipe without (automatic) waiting for the other program. The optimal buffer size used to write/read from pipes is independent of the best block size for any other writing/reading of the programs connected to the pipe.

Comment: +1 because of using `dd`'s default stdin instead of cat. Much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ssh tunneled pipe:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 ibs=1M obs=64k | ssh -C user@remotehost "cat > /path/to/destination"
```

The `-C` option enables compression in the ssh protocol which usually improves the performance in cases like this.

If you have `pv` installed, you can include it in the pipe to get more information how much already is transferred.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 ibs=1M obs=64k | pv | ssh -C user@remotehost "cat > /path/to/destination"
```

Comment: why `bs=64k`? Knoppix LiveCD misses the pv. This requires 36 hours at least to run on sparse ntfs -fs.

Comment: `bs`  gives the block size for the transfer. AFAIK, the pipe buffer is 64k big. This is the reason for `bs=64k`. It maybe better to use e.g. `ibs=1M` as in Patrix answer for fast disk reading and `obs=64k` for good pipe performance. See (here)[http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/15241] for more information.  You can install programs in Knoppix based LiveCD systems if you have Internet access. Simply: `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install pv`.

Comment: You mean that pipes will fail if you send 50GB with it? How can I see that it fails?

Comment: No, they do not fail. A pipe is limited queue between programs. On Linux, it has 64k. If the queue is full, the writing program on the one side is automatically blocked until the program on the other side reads data from the pipe. Therefore it make sense to write in blocks which fits into the queue. I've done now some pipe speed measurements. I see no big difference between values between `obs=64k` and  `obs=8k`. Without any proof, it seems that `obs=16k` works best for me. But in our case, network or disk speed are the limiting factor, so `obs=` is not really important if it is not too small.

Comment: ..yes but what about if I do not specify the setting?

Comment: @hhh Then the default 512 byte block size is used. See the man page of `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `scp` which comes with every Linux Distribution. It is called secure copy.

`$ scp -r folder-to-copy location-of-copy`

Comment: ...this is about cloning `/dev/sdb2` (it is a harddrive), it is not a traditional dir or?