# ps output / pipeline execution order

Tags: bash, pipe, ps

I run `ps aux | grep somethinghere`.

The output shows the `grep somethinghere` as a running process.

My question is, shouldn't `ps aux` finish first, then `grep somethinghere` run on its output? Maybe there is no need for `ps` to finish (there is a pipe between them), but it should run as the first process, while `grep` isn't running.

The output means that `grep` is ran before `ps`!

How is this? Shouldn't `ps` run first, because its output should be piped to `grep`?
Even if they are ran at the same time, why is that I always see `grep` in output? Shouldn't I not see `grep` sometimes, too?

Comment: You have 100+ rep and really consider "Explain this please" an acceptable question title?

Comment: @HaukeLaging suppose OP mean what I indicate in my answer but didn't able to explain it.

Comment: Sorry @HaukeLaging, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [this page](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps%20aux%20%7C%20grep%20-i%20apache).

---

Edit, now that I understand what you are asking:

Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37513/82289) will better help explain.

> The order the commands are run actually doesn't matter and isn't guaranteed. Leaving aside the arcane details of pipe(), fork(), dup() and execve(), the shell first creates the pipe, the conduit for the data that will flow between the processes, and then creates the processes with the ends of the pipe connected to them. The first process that is run may block waiting for input from the second process, or block waiting for the second process to start reading data from the pipe. These waits can be arbitrarily long and don't matter. Whichever order the processes are run, the data eventually gets transferred and everything works.

Comment: Good link, thanks. But it doesn't mention the execution order, anyway

Comment: "So the only output you see is from grep." What relation does that have to the question?

Comment: @HaukeLaging What do you mean what relation does this have? `The output means that grep is ran before ps!` I believe OP is confused as to why despite `ps` running first you don't see the complete output first then grep's. I am trying to clarify that `ps` does run first but because the output is piped to grep that the only thing displayed is the filtered result.

Comment: @DevNull No I didn't mean this. I know at last I see `grep`'s output, but the question is why the process `grep` is included in the output of `ps`? Shouldn't `grep` run after `ps`?

Comment: @thelastblack Oh, that makes more sense now. I believe the answer to that is because before `ps` can execute, 'pipe' waits `ps` until `grep` is ready for the output of `ps`, because of this, `grep` is actually running when `ps` executes therefore it is in the results.

Comment: That the output comes from `grep` doesn't say anything about the problem.

Comment: “`ps aux` runs first” is wrong (as the text you quote explains). The two sides of the pipe run in parallel. Which program is started first is unpredictable.

Comment: @Gilles you are 100% correct. At first I didn't understand what OP was asking. I removed the incorrect statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that OP mean "How to strip `grep somethinghere` process from `ps` output list of `somethinghere` prosesses".
There are dozen way to do it:

1. If you need just number you can use `pgrep -l somethinghere`
2. Double **grep** `ps aux | grep somethinghere | grep -v grep` (have met ofen but I do not like it)
3. Make some regexp with `somethinghere` `ps aux | grep [s]omethinghere`

Comment: I didn't mean this. I meant why is `grep` showing in `ps` output, while it should run after `ps`?

Comment: @thelastblack Now I see. The "pipe" do not mean that the second command run after first ones just redirect output of the first command to input of the second. More over, I think to be able to provide the action shell have to start second command fist to make its input to be ready to receive information from the first command. To avoid this you can use "named pipes" (info is easy can be found here on the site)