# Function of second grep in `ps | grep -v | grep`

Tags: grep, ps

```
ps aux  | grep firefox
```

Lists all processes having the string "firefox"

```
ps aux  | grep -v firefox
```

Lists all the processes without the string "firefox"

`ps aux  | grep -v grep | grep firefox` ?

What does this second grep does ? grep itself is a command then why we are grepping another grep ?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run

Answer (score 18):

When you do a command such as

```
ps aux  | grep firefox
```

Then the `grep` process *itself* may show in the output because the word you are looking for is present.  e.g. on my machine I run `chrome` and the similar results:

```
% ps aux | grep chrome
sweh      3384  0.0  0.0  11128  1024 pts/1    S+   07:08   0:00 grep chrome
sweh     23698  0.0  0.0   6384   620 ?        S    Jul04   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
```

We can see process 3384 is the `grep` command and matches because the word *chrome* shows up.

To avoid this some people then add a second `| grep -v grep` to remove that line.

There is a *cheat* though...

```
ps aux | grep '[f]irefox'
```

`grep '[f]irefox'` matches exactly the same lines as `grep firefox`, but now the `grep` command will never match itself because the word doesn't literally appear on that command.

Comment: You call is a *cheat*, but it's actually much cleaner than the `grep -v grep` workaround!

Comment: This cheat is OP.

Answer (score 9):

The `ps` command will output all your currently running processes. The first `grep` will remove the `grep` process from this list. The second will extract any `firefox` process in the filtered list.

This is probably a partial attempt to get the process ID (PID) of the `firefox` process, possibly just to see if it's running, or to terminate it.

If this is the case, I strongly advise you to use `pgrep` (or `pkill`, if it's process termination you're after) instead:

```
if pgrep firefox 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "firefox is already running"
else
  echo "starting firefox..."
  firefox &
done
```

To terminate `firefox`:

```
pkill firefox
```

That is, *don't* go the long way around finding its PID first.

See also the manuals for `pgrep` and `pkill` on your system.

Comment: Upvoted, since `pgrep` is way better than `| grep -v grep` and the cheat mentioned by Stephen. Links to their manual pages are appreciated though.

Comment: @FranklinYu There are slightly different implementations of `pgrep` and `pkill` available depending on the Unix one is using.  One should always read the manual installed on one's own machine.

Answer (score 4):

Analyzing `ps aux  | grep -v grep | grep firefox`

`ps aux` will give you the output of processes.
The first grep (`grep -v grep`) will remove any line that will be feeded in it from `ps aux` that will contain the word `grep`. After the output will be grepped again (`grep firefox`) for the word `firefox` and give you the output.

Comment: The commands after second pipe. `grep firefox` , Wouldn't that add another grep process in the list after filtering  grep processes through commands next to first pipe ?

Comment: you eliminate the occurance of grep with `grep -v grep`. like @ilkkachu said try to `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep hello` output will be null

Comment: Seems I understand that. But again doubt that because you are adding another grep in pipe at the last. Why doesn't last grep process list there ?
Probably that's how Linux is designed to work I suppose.

Comment: The only thing that looks for the processes currently running, is the `ps`. When it runs, either there is a grep (or several) in the list it sees and prints, or there isn't. The output of `ps` goes to `grep` as just a string of text. At that point if doesn't matter if new processes appear, `ps` didn't see them, so they are not in the text seen by the `grep` processes. Then both `grep` commands remove part of their input text and output the rest.