# Matching for program names, why so many hits?

Tags: grep, scripting, ps

In my box, the code `/bin/ps -aux | /bin/grep -c "blynk"`returns a 1 because blynk server is not running.

However, when the same code is ran in a bash file, it returns 4. How does that happen?

```
#!/bin/sh
stat=`/bin/ps -aux | /bin/grep -c "blynk"`
if [ $stat -lt "2" ]; then
    echo not running
else 
    echo running
    date
fi
```

Comment: As always, read and heed Greg Wooledge's advice on the matter of parsing the process tree, hyperlinked in an answer to a related question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377296/ and given by other people all over the place here including in answer comments at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295363/ .

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent `grep` from finding itself. An easy way to do that is this:

```
/bin/ps -aux | /bin/grep -c "[b]lynk"
```

That way `grep` searches for `blynk` without having it in its command line. Or you prevent `grep` from running at the same time:

```
/bin/ps -aux >ps.txt
/bin/grep -c "[b]lynk" ps.txt
```

Of course, it makes sense to not grep command lines at all because you would also find editors which were opened with a file `README.blynk`.

Thus it is better to use `pgrep` or modify the `ps` output, limit it to command names or command paths.

Answer (score 0):

You get a higher number from the `grep` because there are more programs running that match the pattern.

If you look at the output of `grep` (without the `-c`), you'll see which lines in the output of `ps` match. E.g. if I make a script like this, I get three:

```
$ cat check_blynk.sh
#!/bin/bash
foo=$(/bin/ps a | /bin/grep "blynk")
echo "$foo"

$ bash check_blynk.sh
28874 pts/11   S+     0:00 bash check_blynk.sh
28875 pts/11   S+     0:00 bash check_blynk.sh
28877 pts/11   S+     0:00 /bin/grep blynk
```

That's one for the `grep`, since the pattern it uses matches itself, one for script that just so happens to contain the same word in its name, and *another* for the fact that the `ps | grep` is running in a subshell, i.e. another copy of the shell. (I'm not sure what the fourth one would be.)

You might want to use something like `pgrep -c blynk` instead, assuming `blynk` is the name of program file. `pgrep` by default checks the actual file name of the running program, instead of the whole command line. (With `-f` it checks the command line, but the you'll match the Bash script again)

Comment: Thanks but i need a numeric answer so if the blynk server is not running I can start it via the same bash file

Comment: @Emilio, I though you asked "how" it happens that the result is what it is. You'll see exactly what they are, if you run the grep without `-c`. And `pgrep -c` is another way to get a count, etc.

Comment: like: `#!/bin/sh
#
#Watchdog script for blynk server
#
stat=`/bin/ps -aux | /bin/grep -c "blynk"`
server="/volume1/blynk/server-0.29.5-java8.jar"
if [ $stat -lt "2" ]; then
/var/packages/Java8/target/j2sdk-image/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /volume1/homes/admin/$server -serverConfig /volume1/homes/admin/blynk_config/server.properties -dataFolder /volume1/homes/admin/blynk_data &
fi`

Comment: @Emilio, please don't put code in comments like that, the formatting doesn't work and the result looks awful. If you're wondering how to change the grep pattern to only match the process you want, it would help if you stated that in [your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/417043/edit), and also add the exact command line you are trying to match. That way it would be easier to identify where false hits come from.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's my first time here.

Answer (score 0):

A `bash` function to check if a process of a command is running, defunct (zombie, dead) excluded:

```
_isRunning() {
    ps -o comm= -C "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -x "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

**Note:** `ps` reports defunct processes too, so, `grep -x` is used

Example usages:

```
if _isRunning blynk; then
  echo not running
else 
  echo running
  date
fi
```