# How to copy a directory which root can't access to a directory that only root can access?

Tags: permissions, root, file-copy

I have a directory on an nfs mount, which on the server is at `/home/myname/.rubies`

Root cannot access this directory:

```
[mitchell.usher@server ~]$ stat /home/mitchell.usher/.rubies
  File: `/home/mitchell.usher/.rubies'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 32768  directory
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 245910      Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  970/mitchell.usher)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2016-08-22 15:06:15.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2016-08-22 14:55:00.000000000 +0000
Change: 2016-08-22 14:55:00.000000000 +0000

[mitchell.usher@server ~]$ sudo !!
sudo stat /home/mitchell.usher/.rubies
stat: cannot stat `/home/mitchell.usher/.rubies': Permission denied
```

I am attempting to copy something from within that directory to `/opt` which only root has access to:

```
[mitchell.usher@server ~]$ cp .rubies/ruby-2.1.3/ -r /opt
cp: cannot create directory `/opt/ruby-2.1.3': Permission denied

[mitchell.usher@server ~]$ sudo !!
sudo cp .rubies/ruby-2.1.3/ -r /opt
cp: cannot stat `.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/': Permission denied
```

Obviously I can do the following (and is what I've done for the time being):

```
[mitchell.usher@server ~]$ cp -r .rubies/ruby-2.1.3/ /tmp/
[mitchell.usher@server ~]$ sudo cp -r /tmp/ruby-2.1.3/ /opt/
```

Is there any way to do this that wouldn't involve copying it as an intermediary step or changing permissions?

Comment: `cp -Rp /home/mitchell.usher/.rubies /tmp/templocation; sudo mv /tmp/templocation/ruby-2.1.3 /opt` will this not work ? If no, why ?

Comment: @MelBurslan that's what I did, as stated in the question. But let's say it's a 50 GB file that won't fit anywhere else on the filesystem, then I wouldn't be able to `cp <file> /tmp/tmpfile`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `tar` as a buffer process

```
cd .rubies
tar cf - ruby-2.1.3 | ( cd /opt && sudo tar xvfp - )
```

The first `tar` runs as you and so can read your home directory; the second `tar` runs under `sudo` and so can write to `/opt`.

Comment: How is this on memory? If I have a 10 GB file, is that going to fill 10 GB of memory before it pipes and un-tars, or will it un-tar as it tars?

Comment: They run in parallel; a typical pipe has a 64Kbyte buffer.  Nothing to worry about :-)  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer for pipe size details.

Comment: See also [In what order do piped commands run?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/23408) (in particular, [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/23408#144033)).

Comment: `cpio` can be used in much the same way.

Comment: If you have GNU tar, you can save the subshell by using its `-C` argument to change directory (i.e. `tar cf - ruby-2.1.3 | sudo tar -C /opt xpf -`).  Might be worth mentioning that you want to ensure that `sudo` won't ask your password (e.g. through a `sudoers` entry or cached credentials).

Comment: @TobySpeight Why do you need to prevent it from asking for a password? Unless you're running this unattended, but that's true for any unattended use of `sudo`.

Comment: @Barmar - because its stdin is coming from a pipe, not from your terminal.  So how are you going to give it the password?

Comment: `sudo` will read the password from `/dev/tty` and not from stdin.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `rsync` or `scp` to copy from `user@localhost` to the local directory.

Example for `rsync`:

```
# rsync "$real_user@localhost:$PWD/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3" /opt
```

You could alternatively

```
$ rsync .rubies/ruby-2.1.3 "root@localhost:/opt"
```

if you let root access localhost directly (not recommended; we normally prefer root access to be via `sudo`).

Answer (score -4):

You can make a second entry in the FAT (or whatever).
I do this for my `HOSTS` file. I have a link in a writable directory that refers to the file and it has different permissions, so I have `/Hosts/HOSTS` that I can modify easily, and the changes are put in both (i.e. "the one") file(s). It's 2 entries for 1 file. I don't remember the command, sorry.

For you, you make a link to `/opt` for all the files in `.rubies`, and when you change anything in `/opt`, it is the same file as in `.rubies`.

Comment: This is false and misleading, besides not answering the question.

Comment: It is only false because we're dealing with a different file system.  The answerer was obviously referring to hard links which do operate as mentioned, although not applicable for this question.

Comment: Thanks Wildcard, I had a line in my answer about getting a bunch of flack but it was edited out when Michael improved it. :p