# netcat pipe running too early?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, command-substitution, netcat

I have the following script running in the background:

```
while true; do
    { file=$(/somescript); echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"; cat $file; } | nc -l -p 20000
done
```

It works fine, except that `/somescript` is executed once instantly, before even any request is made to port 20000, and then it waits and responds correctly.

What am I doing wrong? It's supposed to run `/somescript` only when there's a request 20000

Answer (score 1):

Note: Question was edited (pipeline reversed) after writing this. I will update if I find time to do so.

Each part of a pipeline is started concurrently with the others. The only thing synchronising the pipeline is I/O, i.e. a process waiting for another process in the pipeline to read its output or provide input.

Your `somescript` script will have to wait and watch the input from `nc` for a request before outputting a filename.

Not knowing what the script does, I can only speculate that it may have some issues with parsing.

Comment: does it mean that `nc` outputs something when it starts? should I just supress errors etc.?

Comment: also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run

Comment: @user224371 I don't know what your `nc` does (mine doesn't output anything, and also doesn't have a `-p` flag). In any case, your script needs to wait until it sees the standard HTTP `GET` request.