# What does "w" do with urandom?

Tags: random, w

```
> strace w 2>&1 | grep urandom
read(4, "/usr/bin/grep\0urandom\0", 2047) = 22
>
```

Why does "w" need urandom? How to avoid this?

UPDATE:

```
> strace w 2>&1 | awk '/urandom/'
read(4, "awk\0/urandom/\0", 2047)       = 14
>
```

so it is the filtering that has something to do with urandom?

```
> strace who 2>&1 | grep urandom
>
```

Then why isn't "who" affected?

Comment: It's not `w` which needs `urandom`. It's becase `Piped commands run concurrently`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Makes sense. There is no `urandom` access in `w`
 source code.

Comment: You're seeing the second command in the pipeline, your `grep` and your `awk`. It's not `w` opening the `/dev/urandom` device file. It's similar to `ps -aux | grep grep`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: correct, I also checked it to make sure. I think this question could be now marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Kusalananda: can you please post this as anser? How to filter it out? :)

Comment: @MarinaAla I'm not on a machine that has `strace` so can't test anything. Others will take it and write something good, I'm sure.

Comment: You can ask the question about unicorns: `strace w 2>&1 | grep unicorns` ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in other answers and comments the reason for what you
observe is the way `Bash` handles pipes. In order to filter what you
really want in similar situations you can try to enclose the first letter of the `grep` argument in `[]` like this:

```
$ strace w 2>&1 | grep random
read(4, "grep\0random\0", 2047)         = 12
$ strace w 2>&1 | grep '[r]andom'
$ strace w 2>&1 | grep '[c]lose'
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
(...)
```

**EDIT:**

As correctly noted by [R.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6342/r) in the [comment below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6342/r) in fact `strace` does
not see the other side of the pipe. Similarly to `ps aux | grep grep`
which also shows `grep grep` in its output `w` is is walking through
`/proc` directory and finds `grep` process there.

Comment: Happy to see someone else doing this (although I usually bracket the last letter instead) with ps/strace etc.  Easiest way to keep it from finding its own command line.

Comment: This trick seems to be becoming widely known. I've heard that it is listed in some FAQs, and it's mentioned many times here on [SE].

Comment: This answer, and the comments on the question itself saying roughly the same thing, are simply wrong. The other answer (by ilkkachu) is right. `strace` does not (and cannot, in any easy way) trace the other commands in the shell pipeline. Rather, `w` is looking up the current commands being executed on your terminal (and other terminals), and runs across the grep as part of its work.

Comment: Correct, thx, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 15):

[From the manpage `w(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/w.1.html):

> **w** displays information about the users currently on the
>       machine, *and their processes*

To display the users' processes, it goes through all processes running on the machine. Let's try this:

```
$ strace -o w.trace w | grep whatever
```

Inside the trace we find lines like these (on a Linux system):

```
open("/proc/8286/cmdline", O_RDONLY)    = 4
read(4, "grep\0whatever\0", 2047)       = 14
```

Which shows `w` explicitly going through `/proc` and looking at the command lines of all processes (and other things, not shown). It finds the `grep` that runs parallel to it and that's what `strace` sees it do. The pipe has nothing to do with it, other than starting both processes at the same time. In a way, it is similar to `ps | grep` seeing the grep itself.

`who` and most other commands don't need the information about the processes, and don't go looking, so you don't see the same when tracing them.