# How did UNIX programs interact with each other, before the invention of the pipe?

Tags: pipe, historical-unix

I read recently, that the concept of a pipe did not come about before UNIX version 3.

But since UNIX was always about simple programs, that do one thing, composed to do more complex things: How did they manage that, without pipes in the first place?

Comment: Shared memory is my first guess.

Comment: The _concept_ of a pipe, as invented by Doug McIlroy, pre-dates all versions of Unix by at least half a decade.  You are talking about the shell syntax and system call.

Comment: It's not quite clear that McIlroy invented the concept. Ritchie mentions that a pipeline is a specific form of coroutine (with the implication that that concept existed "in the ether"). He also mentions that an implementation existed in the "communication files" of the Dartmouth Time Sharing system. But there is no question that McIlroy *was* the force that pushed pipes into Unix. See [Ritchie's article on the evolution of Unix](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/aosref/ritchie84evolution.pdf).

Comment: JdeBP is right — before the invention of the pipe, people communicated with smoke signals and carrier pigeons. Pipes have been around for a ***long*** time.

Comment: @Scott Abraham Lincoln had a pipe. Computers didn't start using carrier pigeons until 1990: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149

Comment: The question is: were they using their pipes to send smoke signals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IO redirection was not present in the initial PDP-7 implementation (circa 1969) but was added very shortly thereafter. With that, you can implement the moral equivalent of a pipe:

```
prog1 | prog2
```

could be implemented with

```
prog1 > tempfile
prog2 < tempfile
rm tempfile
```

In fact, pipes are often *explained* using this model.

The paper [The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/aosref/ritchie84evolution.pdf) by Ritchie
is highly recommended for early Unix history. 
It states, "Pipes appeared in Unix in 1972".

Comment: Suggest you copy the referenced link into your answer, so your answer can stand in its entirety

Comment: Loosely related:  [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/23408)

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for adding the reference (and also for adding the years).

Comment: HTML version is at https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html

Comment: The 'moral equivalent of a pipe' was actually revived (briefly) for Mini-UNIX.