# how we can pipe endless commands like yes?

Tags: pipe

As far as I know piping command `A` to command `B` will execute `A` and give it's output to `B` as input. While some commands are endless, like `yes`, and therefore execution time for these commands is until we break them. How is piping work for them?

example :
`yes | sudo dnf install pkg`

Comment: [What happens when writing gigabytes of data to a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/626975/73093)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although command A might produce an endless output, command B will only read a finite amount of it. When command B exits (or closes its input file descriptor), the pipe will be broken.

After that, any write into the pipe from command A will cause the kernel to send a `SIGPIPE` signal to command A. The default action of `SIGPIPE` is to terminate the process.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you mean both A and B will start execution simultaneously but B waits until receives any input from A?

Comment: Yes, both A and B will run in parallel. B may wait for input, or in some cases it might not read any input from the pipe at all (e.g. `yes | echo 'This does not use the output of "yes" at all'`). In cases where B won't read input from the pipe, A will run until the pipe's buffer capacity is full, and then A will wait until either B has read at least some of it, or the pipe is broken. Optionally, A may set `O_NONBLOCK` on the pipe, in which case the kernel will report a full buffer to A, instead of making it wait. See `man 7 pipe` for more information on pipes.