# How does a FIFO (named pipe) differs from a regular pipe (unnamed pipe)?

Tags: pipe, fifo

How does a FIFO (named pipe) differs from a regular pipe (|)? As I understand from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), unlike a regular pipe, a FIFO pipe "keeps living" after the process has ended and can be deleted sometime afterwards.

But if f the process is based on a shell command containing a pipe (`cat x | grep y`), we could "keep it alive after the process" if we store it in a variable or a file, isn't it then a FIFO?

Also, a regular pipe also has the *first stdout it gets, as stdin for another command*, so isn't it also a kind of first in first out pipe as well?

Comment: Related (background reading): [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/80216)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Named pipe" is actually a *very* accurate name for what it is — it is just like a regular pipe, except that it has a name (on a filesystem).

A pipe — the regular, un-named ("anonymous") one used in `some-command | grep pattern` is a special kind of file. And I do mean file, you read and write to it just like you do every other file. Grep doesn't really care¹ that it's reading from a pipe instead of a terminal³ or an ordinary file.

Technically, what goes on behind the scenes is that stdin, stdout, and stderr are three open files (file descriptors) passed to every command run. File descriptors (which are used in every syscall to read/write/etc. files) are just numbers; stdin, stdout, and stderr are file descriptors 0, 1, and 2. So when your shell sets up `some-command | grep` what it does is something this:

1. Asks the kernel for an anonymous pipe. There is no name, so this can't be done with `open` like for a normal file — instead it's done with `pipe` or `pipe2`, which returns two file descriptors.⁴
2. Forks off a child process (`fork()` creates a copy of the parent process; both sides of the pipe are open here), copies the write-side of the pipe to fd 1 (stdout). The kernel has a syscall to copy around file descriptor numbers; it's `dup2()` or `dup3()`. It then closes the read side and other copy of the write side. Finally, it uses `execve` to execute `some-command`. Since the pipe is fd 1, stdout of `some-command` is the pipe.
3. Forks of another child process. This time, it duplicates the read side of the pipe to fd 0 (stdin), and executes `grep`. So grep will read from the pipe as stdin.
4. Then it waits for both of those children to exit.
5. At this point, the kernel notices that the pipe isn't open any more, and garbage collects it. That's what actually destroys the pipe.

A named pipe just gives that anonymous pipe a name by putting it in the filesystem. So now *any* process, at any point in the future, can obtain a file descriptor for the pipe by using an ordinary `open` syscall. Conceptually, the pipe won't be destroyed until both all readers/writers have closed it and it's `unlink`ed from the filesystem.²

This, by the way, is how files in general work on Unix. `unlink` (the syscall behind `rm`) just removes one of the names for the file; only when all names are removed and nothing has the file open will it actually be deleted. A couple of answers here explore this:

- [Why do hard links seem to take the same space as the originals?](/q/88423)
- [How can a log program continue to log to a deleted file?](/q/146929)
- [What is Linux doing differently that allows me to remove/replace files where Windows would complain the file is currently in use?](/q/49299)

*FOOTNOTES*

1. Technically this probably isn't true — it's probably possible to do some optimizations by knowing, and actual grep implementations have often been heavily optimized. But conceptually it doesn't care (and indeed a straightforward implementation of grep wouldn't).
2. Of course the kernel doesn't actually keep all the data structures around in memory forever, but rather it recreates them, transparently, whenever the first program opens the named pipe (and then keeps them as long as its open). So it's as if they existed as long as the name does.
3. Terminal isn't a common place for grep to read from, but it's the default stdin when you don't specify another. So if you type just `grep pattern` in to your shell, `grep` will be reading from the terminal. The only use for this that comes to mind is if you're about to paste something to the terminal.
4. On Linux, anonymous pipes actually are created on a special filesystem, pipefs. See [How pipes work in Linux](/q/148401) for details. Note that this is an internal implementation detail of Linux.

Comment: Some `grep` implementations have an option to `mmap` input files if possible, instead of `read()`ing.  (GNU `grep` no longer has such an option, if it ever did, because it's usually not a performance win these days.)  This is of course only possible for regular file and block devices, not anonymous or named pipes.  Most `grep` implementations would want to seek in their input, but if `stdin` is a regular file, it's seekable.  This matters for stuff like a video file: `cat foo.mkv | mpv -` vs. `<foo.mkv  mpv -`.  The latter will notice that stdin is seekable and take advantage.

Comment: @PeterCordes yep, that'd be one of those optimizations (if it actually were more optimal). There are no doubt others, like reading in large chunks or maybe someone even has a multithreaded grep.

Comment: `Grep doesn't really care¹ that it's reading from a pipe instead of a terminal`, what is greap reading from terminal? Never came across such need, and thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, of course a pipe is a file, but it is so unintuitive to a newbiew like myself to think of it as a file. I do get the notion that it is first just part of a command, but when Bash interpret the command, it is a file created somewhere: If it is a regular pipe, it is a temporary file, if it is a named pipe (FIFO) it is much less temporary. I edited the answer to add: `When typing a command, both pipes are just syntax but when the shell interpret the command, they are both files. A regular pipe is temporary, and a named pipe ("FIFO") is permanent, at least by definition.`

Comment: Also, would you say the name "FIFO" is misleading when used just for a named pipe?

Comment: You're using system call names in the first part of your answer and then switch to (common) applications names (`rm`) in the second. Wouldn't it be more consistent to refer to `unlink` instead since that is also what the kernel does to the file? That would also work out better for grammar: “`rm`’d” vs. `unlink`ed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you, I think I've fixed that and now consistently use syscall names.

Comment: @user9303970 If you just type `grep pattern`, it'll be reading from the terminal as stdin. Usually not that useful (maybe if you're going to paste something to the terminal).

Comment: Hmm @derobert maybe good to add a footnote.

Comment: @user9303970 I'm not sure if it'll help the unintuitiveness or just make it worse, but... remember that files themselves are just an abstraction provided by the kernel. The physical reality of charges in some capacitors (SSD), magnetized iron compounds (hard disk, tape), pits in a reflective layer (CD/DVD/BD), etc., don't actually know about files. Neither does the storage hardware above that. Files only exist once you have the kernel (or something else providing the abstraction) running. So it's not *that* weird to use the same abstraction for other things—If it acts like a file, it's a file.

Comment: @user9303970 FIFO is a name from its behavior: the first thing written ("first in") is the first thing read ("first out"). It's a somewhat odd name, though, since e.g., stream sockets work the same way, but aren't called FIFOs.

Comment: @user9303970 Added two more footnotes for you.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're getting mixed up between shell syntax for pipelines vs. the underlying Unix systems programming.  A pipe / FIFO is a type of file that isn't stored on disk, but instead passed data from a writer to a reader through a buffer in the kernel.

A pipe/FIFO works the same whether the writer and reader got connected by making system calls like `open("/path/to/named_pipe", O_WRONLY);`, or with a [`pipe(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to create a new anonymous pipe and return open file descriptors to both the read and write sides.

**[`fstat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) on the pipe file descriptor will give you `sb.st_mode & S_IFMT == S_IFIFO` either way.**

---

**When you run `foo | bar`**:

- The shell forks like normal for any non-builtin command
- Then makes a `pipe(2)` system call to get two file descriptors: the input and output of an anonymous pipe.
- Then it forks *again*.
- **The child** (where `fork()` returned 0)

  - closes the read side of the pipe (leaving the write fd open)
  - and redirects `stdout` to the write fd with `dup2(pipefd[1], 1)`
  - then does `execve("/usr/bin/foo", ...)`
- **The parent** (where `fork()` returned the non-0 child PID)

  - closes the write side of the pipe (leaving the read fd open)
  - and redirects `stdin` from the read fd with `dup2(pipefd[0], 0)`
  - then does `execve("/usr/bin/bar", ...)`

**You get into a very similar situation if you run `foo > named_pipe & bar < named_pipe`.**

A named pipe is a rendezvous for processes to establish pipes between each other.

---

The situation is similar to anonymous tmp files vs. files with names.  You can `open("/path/to/dir", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);` to create a temporary file *with no name* (`O_TMPFILE`), as if you'd opened `"/path/to/dir/tmpfile"` with `O_CREAT` and then unlinked it, leaving you with a file descriptor to a deleted file.

Using `linkat`, you can even link that anonymous file into the filesystem, giving it a name, if it was created with `O_TMPFILE`.  ([You can't do this on Linux for files that you created with a name then deleted, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171713/relinking-an-anonymous-unlinked-but-open-file))