# Understanding piped commands in Unix/Linux

Tags: pipe, terminology

I have two simple programs: `A` and `B`. `A` would run first, then `B` gets the “stdout” of `A` and uses it as its “stdin”. Assume I am using a GNU/Linux operating system and the simplest possible way to do this would be:

```
./A | ./B
```

If I had to describe this command, I would say that it is a command that takes input (i.e., reads) from a producer (`A`) and writes to a consumer (`B`). Is that a correct description? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Related: [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/80216)

Comment: It's not command, it's an kenerl object created by bash process, which is used as stdout of process A and stdin as B. Two processes are started nearly at the same time.

Comment: @炸鱼  You're correct - for kernel pipeline is an object in pipefs filesystem, but as far as shell itself is concerned - technically that's a pipeline command

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only thing about your question that stands out as *wrong* is that you say

> A would run first, then B gets the stdout of A

In fact, both programs would be started at pretty much the same time.  If there's no input for `B` when it tries to read, it will block until there is input to read.  Likewise, if there's nobody reading the output from `A`, its writes will block until its output is read (some of it will be buffered by the pipe).

The only thing synchronising the processes that take part in a pipeline is the I/O, i.e. the reading and writing across the pipe.  If no writing or reading happens, then the two processes will run totally independent of each other. If one ignores the reading or writing of the other, the ignored process will block and eventually be killed by a `SIGPIPE` signal (if writing) or get an end-of-file condition on its standard input stream (if reading) when the other process terminates.

The idiomatic way to describe `A | B` is that it's a pipeline containing two programs.  The output produced on standard output from the first program is available to be read on the standard input by the second ("[the output of] `A` is piped into [the input of] `B`").  The shell does the required plumbing to allow this to happen.

If you want to use the words "consumer" and "producer", I suppose that's ok too.

The fact that these are programs written in C is not relevant. The fact that this is Linux, macOS, OpenBSD or AIX is not relevant.

Comment: Actually, we can think of having A and B running in parallel as an optimization. The command is equivalent to `./A > tmp_file && ./B < tmp_file`, which first save the output of A to `tmp_file` and then give it as an input to B. This information is taken from: http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/monadic-shell.html (I change the command slightly)

Comment: What I think OP have in mind is the unoptimized implementation of pipe (which is almost never used in practice).

Comment: Writing to a temporary file was used in DOS, as that didn't support multiple processes.

Comment: @AlexVong Note though that your example with a temporary file is not exactly equivalent. A program may choose to seek though the contents of a file, but data coming off a pipe is not seekable. A better examlp would be to use `mkfifo` to create a named pipe, then start B in the background reading from the pipe, and then A writing to it. This is nit-picking though, as the _effect_ would be the same.

Comment: The `&&` is another problem with Alex’s suggested implementation — `B` will always run, unconditionally, so it’s more like `./A > tmp_file; ./B < tmp_file`.  And, of course, there’s also the `rm tmp_file` at the end.

Comment: @AlexVong The simplifications made in that article divorce it from real pipelines; the parallel execution is truly semantic, not an optimisation. It's a reasonable lies-to-children explanation *of monadic evaluation* or composition for someone who's seen shell pipelines, but it's not valid in the other direction. Kusalananda's fifo version is closer, but the error propagation parts of the model are genuinely important and not replicable. (all of which I say as someone who is very on the "shell pipelines are just function composition" train)

Comment: "The fact that this is Linux, macOS, OpenBSD or AIX is not relevant." Well, not exactly. Pipes on FeeBSD are bidirectional (see https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pipe(2)) so there's that bit to keep in mind. But the general gist of pipelines is the same

Comment: @AlexVong No, that's *completely* off track. That isn't able to explain even something simple like  `yes | sed 10q`

Comment: @UncleBilly I agree with your example. This shows that parallel execution is really required also noted by Michael. Otherwise, we'll get non-termination.

Answer (score 2):

The term usually used in documentation is "pipeline" , which consists of one or more commands, [see POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02)  So technically speaking, that's two commands you have there, two subprocesses for the shell (either `fork()+exec()`'ed external commands or subshells )

As for [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) part,  the pipeline can be described by that pattern, since:

- Producer and Consumer share fixed-size buffer, and at least on Linux and MacOS X, there's [fixed size for pipeline buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer)
- Producer and Consumer are loosely-coupled, commands in pipeline don't know of each other's existence ( unless they are actively checking `/proc/<pid>/fd` directory ).
- Producers write to `stdout` and consumers read `stdin` as if they were a single command being executed, aka they [can exist without each other](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286763/difference-between-consumer-producer-and-observer-observable).

The difference I see here is that unlike Producer-Consumer in other languges, shell commands use buffering and they write stdout once buffer is filled, but there's no mention that Producer-Consumer has to follow that rule - only wait when queue is filled or discard data (which is something else that pipeline doesn't do).