# Is it possible for sendmail to not use all the output from a bash subshell piped to it?

Tags: bash, sendmail, subshell

( GNU bash, version 4.2.50(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.2.0))

```
(
echo "a"
echo "b"
echo "c"
)| sendmail -F "Sender" recipients@a.com
```

This runs inside a .sh file, and the log (when ran with the -x option) show the  `sendmail` before `echo "c"`.

I am trying to debug why sendmail fails sporadically.  Since the subshell and sendmail run in parallel, is it possible for  sendmail to not wait for the whole subshell to be over, and use only the partial output until `echo b` and proceed to send an incomplete email and then fail? (There are no error messages in  stderr though, the email just doesn't show up in my inbox mysteriously for some executions)

For more context:
The echo commands I wrote above are just placeholders, I am actually trying to prepare an email as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335377/11521011 and pipe it to sendmail

Comment: I'm guessing you're actual issue doesn't involve simply echoing a,b,c?  There may be something else going on.  Also what logs?

Comment: Also see [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run)

Comment: @Jesse_b  Thanks, I rephrased and added more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used `-i` in `sendmail`'s command line options.

Without it, `sendmail` treats a "single dot only line" as end of message.