# How to prevent curl output from printing a preceding pipe's output?

Tags: pipe, curl, gpg

I have a command piping an encrypted gpg stream into curl:

```
echo "Some Text" | gpg -o - | curl --silent -T - \
-X PUT \
--output /dev/null \
${myurl} \
```

When running this, I see something like

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Enter passphrase

Passphrase:
```

where the `"Enter passphrase"` part is attached to the send of the curl output. I am unable to put in newlines due to the piped nature of things. Is there a way to make the curl output run later?

Comment: Try changing "gpg -o" to "gpg --passwd <user-id> -o".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to prevent curl output from printing a preceding pipe's output?

`curl` does not print the "preceding pipe's output". What happens is `curl` and `gpg` print some messages to your terminal. The messages interfere with each other.

Remember that [piped commands run concurrently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/108618).

---

If you expect the output from successful `gpg` never to be empty then use [`ifne`](https://superuser.com/a/1218219/432690):

```
… | gpg … | ifne curl …
```

(In Debian `ifne` is in the `moreutils` package.)

The main purpose of `ifne` is to prevent a command (here: `curl`) from running if the stdin is empty. To know if the stdin is really empty, the tool needs to wait for any data or EOF. This delays the actual command. A delay is what you need.

I expect `gpg` to start printing only after it gets the right passphrase. I did not test `ifne` thoroughly with preceding `gpg` asking for passphrase, but I did test with `sudo …` asking for password. If `gpg` works as I expect then `ifne` can help you. It will run `curl` after you provide the passphrase.

Note `ifne` will prevent `curl` from running if `gpg` prints nothing to its stdout (e.g. because the passphrase was wrong). This behavior is often desired. However if the output from successful `gpg` can be empty and still should be piped to `curl`, then `ifne` alone is not the right thing.

If you want to run `curl` regardless if `gpg` prints anything then keep reading.

---

The code below is a reduced version of my `report` script from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1612027/432690). Save it as `delay`.

It uses `ifne` in a more complicated way. The code must be an executable script (I mean don't try to make it a shell function) because it calls itself via `ifne "$0"` (and `ifne` cannot run a function).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "-X" ]; then
   marker=1
   fd="$2"
   shift 2
else
   unset marker
   exec {fd}>&1
fi

if [ "$marker" ]; then
   ( >&"$fd" "$@" )
else
   ifne -n "$0" -X "$fd" "$@" | ifne "$0" -X "$fd" "$@"
fi
```

The purpose of `delay` is to delay execution of a command until there is data or EOF in the stdin. It was designed to be used after `|`.

You should use it like this:

```
… | gpg … | delay curl …
```

`curl` will run only after `gpg` starts printing to its stdout or closes for whatever reason.

Some technical details are explained in the [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1612027/432690).

---

The difference between `ifne foo`, `ifne -n foo` and `delay foo`:

- `ifne foo` waits for data or EOF and then runs `foo` iff there is data,
- `ifne -n foo` waits for data or EOF and then runs `foo` iff there is no data,
- `delay foo` waits for data or EOF and then runs `foo` unconditionally.