# Program launches before piped into

Tags: shell, arch-linux, zsh, pipe, zathura

```
man -k . | fzf -e --tiebreak=begin | awk '{print $1}' | xargs man -Tpdf | zathura -
# searches for a man page and then outputs it as pdf to zathura
```

This command lets the user choose a man page, and then displays the page. 
It works great, other than zathura starting blank while it waits for
the user to make their selection, which leads to zathura getting input. 
It is really annoying having to change focus from zathura back to the terminal
and then back to zathura.

I am fairly new to scripting so I thought that there might be a way around this that I just don't know about.

Preferably not `ifne`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent curl output from printing a preceding pipe's output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642443/how-to-prevent-curl-output-from-printing-a-preceding-pipes-output)

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without installing another package? (ifne , moreutils)

Comment: If the linked duplicate is not what you want then [edit] your question and state it there. Put the new requirements (no `ifne`) in the question body. Then I (or somebody else) will probably post an answer that matches your case better. A straightforward solution is: redirect `xargs man …` to a regular file, then let `zathura` read the file.

Comment: Now I recall I have answered [very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515862/108618). **This link is better than the first one.** An approach with a temporary file is in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515865/108618).

Comment: Also similar: [Completely buffer command output before piping to another command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188217/80216)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
name=$( man -k . | fzf +i -e --tiebreak=begin | awk '{print ($2,$1)}' | tr -d "()")
if [ -n "$name" ]; then
man -Tpdf $(echo $name) | zathura - &
fi
```

After thinking better about it I came up with this, works great and now supports all manpages (takes in to consideration the label of the man page e.g `1p ls`)

G-mans answer seems more sophisticated , and without the extra functionality mentioned above ( as it was never asked for , understandably ) .

Answer (score 2):

That's the whole point of pipe lines to run commands concurrently with pipes in between them.

For commands to run sequentially, you'd need pipes of infinite size, or resort to storing output into temporary files.

With `zsh`, that can be done with:

```
zathura =(
  man -k . |
   fzf -e --tiebreak=begin |
   awk '{print $1}' |
   xargs -rd '\n' man -Tpdf
)
```

(here adding the GNU-specific `-r` and `-d '\n'` options as we don't want the default parsing mode of `xargs` and don't want to run `man` if there's no input).

Where `=(cmd)` expands to the path of a temporary file than contains the output of the `cmd` once `cmd` has returned (a third form of *process substitution* specific to `zsh`). The temporary file is automatically removed once the `zathura` command returns.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something here —
I'd never heard of `fzf` (or `zathura`, for that matter)
before I saw this question,
and I don't have them on my system to test with. 
But … isn't the point of `fzf` to pick an item from a list? 
Let me rephrase that:
isn't the point of `fzf` to pick ***one*** item from a list? 
Isn't `xargs` overkill here? 
Isn't the logic basically

```
select a man page
and then display it
```

?

[The `fzf` page at GitHub](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) suggests using `$(fzf args)`. 
The following should work:

```bsh
mp=$(man -k . | fzf -e --tiebreak=begin | awk '{print $1}')  &&  [ -n "$mp" ]  &&
                man -Tpdf "$mp" | zathura - &
```

to read the user-selected man page from the user input
***and then*** display it. 
No need for an (explicit) temporary file. 
(Add `2> /dev/null` if you believe that it's beneficial.)

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" my problem , I redirected output to my /tmp/ directory and then had zathura read from there  . I also put it all in a script .

```
   #!/bin/sh
   d=$(date +'%M_%S');
   man -k . | fzf -e --tiebreak=begin | awk '{print $1}' | xargs man -Tpdf > /tmp/man_${d};
   zathura /tmp/man_${d} 2> /dev/null &
```

EDIT : Not really a Solution ,please don't use this

Comment: Creating files with predictable names in `/tmp` is bad practice from a security standpoint (an attacker could create symlinks `man_{0..60}_{0..60}` symlinks to your `~/.zshrc` for instance and cause that output to be stored there).