# bash: clarification on order of redirection and pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

In an attempt to further understand bash, I am trying to replicate some functionalities of it. Right now I am in the process to implementing the redirecting and pipeline features. To further understand each of these concepts, apart from reading the docs ([redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) and [pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html)), I have been trying some special cases, and I have come up with this case that I am struggling to understand:

```
bash-3.2$ echo test > file | tr -d t < file | wc > file ; cat file
       0       0       0
```

I would expect the output of the command to be        `1       1       3`, but instead it outputs        `0       0       0`. I have tried the same command in zsh and the output is what I expected, so it is seems that some of my assumptions are incorrect for bash. For easier reference, I will consider the command provided as `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd`. This is what I thought that happened when executing the command:

1. *stdout* of *cmd1* is redirected to *stdin* of *cmd2*.
2. *stdout* of *cmd2* is redirected to *stdin* of *cmd3*.
3. *cmd1* is executed:

   1. *file* is created or truncated.
   2. *stdout* of `echo test` is redirected to *file*.
   3. The *echo* command is executed and "test" is saved to *file*.
4. *cmd2* is executed:

   1. *stdin* of `tr -d t` is redirected to *file*.
   2. The *tr* command is executed and the "test" read from *file* becomes "es" and is outputted to *cmd3*.
5. *cmd3* is executed:

   1. *file* is truncated.
   2. *stdout* of `wc` is redirected to *file*.
   3. The *wc* command is executed with "es" as input and "1 1 3" is saved to *file*.

Clearly some of my assumptions are wrong and I would greatly appreciate all the possible corrections to them.

I have also tried other commands such as:

```
bash-3.2$ echo test > file | tr -d t < file | wc >> file ; cat file
test
       1       1       3
```

```
bash-3.2$ echo test > file | tr -d t < file | wc > file2 ; cat file ; cat file2
test
       1       1       3
```

These tests lead me to believe that my assumptions are probably wrong in the order of execution of things or even in the moment that the truncation is happening. Whatever it is, I would gladly appreciate any explanation or further help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run)

Comment: @AdminBee It partially answers it. I was also trying to understand the interaction of redirections combined pipes. Turns out that because of the response to that answer there is no real interaction, so it did clarify something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands in a pipeline run simultaneously, so reading and writing from/to the same file depends on how the processes happen to get scheduled.

In particular, in step 4.2, there's no guarantee the file contains any data when `tr` starts reading from it as a) the `echo` on the left-hand side may not have written anything yet, and b) the redirection in `wc > file` may have truncated the file after `echo` had written it.

I'm not sure why you're using that first pipe there anyway, since the redirections to/from the file override the pipe. What you're doing there is pretty much the same as

```
echo test > file & tr -d t < file | wc > file; wait; cat file
```

which isn't much better in general in that it still contains all the same races, but at least it doesn't have the confusing pipe operator.

Zsh with `multios` is different in that makes multiple output redirections print to *all* targets, and multiple input redirections read from *all* sources. Instead of just the last one like a standard shell.