# output to file, then use file for input

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Is there a shorter way of writing this? Basically output a command to a file, then use the file as input for the next command. I also want to keep the file to view afterwards.

`cmd1 > verylong.txt; cmd2 < verylong.txt`

I know I can do

`cmd1 | tee verylong.txt | cmd2`

But since I expect "verylong.txt" to be a huge file, I thought it would be less efficient to use pipe since that would hold the entire file in memory. Whereas if I use file input then it would process it one line at a time. (Or is my assumption wrong?)

It would be great if I could do something elegant like

`cmd1 > verylong.txt > cmd2`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, `cmd1 | tee verylong.txt | cmd2` will not hold the whole file in memory. In fact, if `cmd2` was to wait too long before consuming its input, `cmd1` might block on a `write` call and unblock only when `cmd2` starts reading again.

The reason for that is that there is a buffer for the pipe, and that buffer, by default, [is limited to a certain reasonable size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer).

Of course, the story might be different if `cmd2` is `sort` (or something alike) where the entire input must be read before the command is able to write its output. In that case, the entire file content might be held in `cmd2` memory, but that is independent of whether a pipe or an intermediary file was used for the input of that command.

Comment: `sort` doesn't store the whole file in memory, it's got a buffer with a maximum size as well and resorts to temporary files when that maximum is reached.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good to know, have an upvote! ;) I'll update the answer to be less assertive in that "hold into memory" part.

Answer (score 6):

The already given answer is correct. But if your goal is to selectively read your `verylongfile.txt` w/ `cmd2`, `sed` might be another option.

```
cmd1 | sed -e 'w verylongfile.txt' -e '/notinteresting/d' | cmd2
```

`sed` will `w`rite all of its input to the outfile, but only the bits that do not match the `/notinteresting/` address to the pipe. Or you might negate the action with `/interesting/!d` which would write only the lines that match the `interesting` address to the pipe.

If this is not your goal, use `tee` instead, though - it is a more efficient tool for writing the whole of its input to both the outfile and the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clever trick with tee and subshells:

```
cat source.lst | tee >(doSomething.sh) >(somethingElse.sh) | somethingFinal.sh
```

I've done this before

```
pv -perl source.list | tee >(doSomething.sh) >(somethingElse.sh) | md5sum
```

`pv` will give you a progress bar, an ETA, and a running line total. Then source.lst will be fed to doSomething.sh and somethingElse.sh (and on different CPUs!) Finally we'll get an md5sum of that hugefile, just for academic purposes.

Answer (score -6):

Whats wrong with simple two line batch file? Like:

```
Cmd1 >filespec
Cmd2 <filespec
```

Or

```
cmd1 >filespec
cmd2 filespec
```

either way, the file is left in mass storage.

Comment: For some reason the site is not letting me key in a less than symbol. and dropping the second part of cmd2. So in words cmd1 redirect out to file. next line cmd2 redirect in from file. OR for cmd2 , just put the filename as the first parameter and cmd2 just opens the file.

Comment: You use `&lt;` for the `<` symbol...

Comment: One difference between `cmd | tee file | cmd` and `cmd >file; cmd <file` is that the commands in the first group are executed in parallel - which is to say that they all start at the same time. And so `cmd2` can process `cmd1`s output as it is written, whereas `cmd1; cmd2` are two commands that are executed one after the other - or, in other words, `cmd2` must wait on `cmd1` to complete before processing anything.

Comment: The author of the question specifically asked for a command that's different from that because the files are very large. Executing the files using your methodology would be a lot slower than cmd1|tee file|cmd2.