# Does tee slow down pipelines?

Tags: pipe, tee

I am wondering whether tee slows down pipelines. Writing data to disk is slower than piping it along, after all.

Does tee wait with sending data through to the next pipe until it has been written to disk? (If not, I guess tee has to queue data that has been sent along, but not written to disk, which sounds unlikely to me.)

```
$ program1 input.txt | tee intermediate-file.txt | program2 ...
```

Comment: No, that "next pipe" is the [very first thing it writes to](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/ec5ab426042d4c2d6add3f9a38c0847cc835a4d6/src/tee.c#L206) (also mentioned [over here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/ec5ab426042d4c2d6add3f9a38c0847cc835a4d6/src/tee.c#L238)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it slows things down. And it basically does have a queue of unwritten data, though that's actually maintained by the kernel—all programs have that, unless they explicitly request otherwise.

For example, here is a trivial pipe using `pv`, which is nice because it displays transfer rate:

```
$ pv -s 50g -S -pteba /dev/zero | cat > /dev/null 
  50GiB 0:00:09 [ 5.4GiB/s] [===============================================>] 100%
```

Now, let's add a `tee` in there, not even writing an extra copy—just forwarding it along:

```
$ pv -s 50g -S -pteba /dev/zero | tee | cat > /dev/null 
  50GiB 0:00:20 [2.44GiB/s] [===============================================>] 100%
```

So, that's quite a bit slower, and it wasn't even doing anything! That's the overhead of tee internally copying STDIN to STDOUT. (Interestingly, adding a second `pv` in there stays at 5.19GiB/s, so `pv` is substantially faster than `tee`. `pv` uses `splice(2)`, `tee` likely does not.)

Anyway, let's see what happens if I tell `tee` to write to a file on disk. It starts out fairly fast (~800MiB/s) but as it goes on, it keeps slowing down—ultimately down to ~100MiB/s, which is basically 100% of the disk write bandwidth. (The fast start is due to the kernel caching the disk write, and the slowdown to disk write speed is the kernel refusing to let the cache grow infinitely.)

### Does it matter?

The above is a worst-case. The above uses a pipe to spew data as fast as possible. The only real-world use I can think of like this is piping raw YUV data to/from `ffmpeg`.

When you're sending data at slower rates (because you're processing them, etc.) it's going to be a much less significant effect.

Comment: Nice explaination

Comment: It actually does matter when you want verbosely script file operations that you need to monitor closely. If your minute-long process outputs 500k lines of diagnostic logs, it makes you feel the difference.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing surprising here, after all

> [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html#tag_20_127_03),

> *DESCRIPTION*
>
> The *tee* utility shall copy standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files. **The *tee* utility shall not buffer output.**

And [also that](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html#tag_20_127_18)

> *RATIONALE*
>
> The buffering requirement means that tee is not allowed to use ISO C standard fully buffered or line-buffered writes. It does not mean that tee has to do 1-byte reads followed by 1-byte writes.

So, without explaining "rationale", `tee` will probably only read and write up to [however many](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer) bytes can fit into your pipe buffer at a time, **flushing the output on every single write.**

And yes, depending on the application, this can be rather inefficient — so feel free to simply remove/comment any of these out:
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c#L208
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c#L224

Comment: +1 for the links to the source code responsible. Are those parts really all that's responsible for this behaviour, so that removing/commenting them out would make `tee` run faster?

Comment: Looks like that would be the case! Tee overrides the buffering scheme that's otherwise chosen by the OS