# dd: write to multiple disks?

Tags: files, dd, output

I have 2 exactly same formatted, same size and same brand SD-cards. 
I would like to `dd` image to `/dev/disk2` and to `/dev/disk3` at the same time.
Pseudocode

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=/Users/masi/2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie.img of={/dev/disk2,/dev/disk3}
```

---

How can you `dd` from one input to many output SDs?

Comment: What's the goal here? Performance? If yes remember the data you read will be cached. So the 2nd dd will you data from your bcache instead of reading (of course you need some free RAM).

Comment: My simplistic test with GNU coreutils dd `... of=one of=two` did not produce two outputs. May need two `dd` commands. I don't see wording in [posix for dd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) to allow for multiple `of`'s.

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz I have 8GB RAM. Possible to get 32GB. Speed is my goal because I have 5 SDs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Borrowing from [*don_crissti*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/284489/1) using `tee`, but without
   `dd` or *bash*isms:

   ```
   sudo tee /dev/disk2 /dev/disk3 > /dev/disk4 < masi.img
   ```
2. Using `pee` from Debian's [*moreutils*](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package:

   ```
   sudo dd if=masi.img | \
     pee "dd of=/dev/disk2"  "dd of=/dev/disk3"  "dd of=/dev/disk4"
   ```

   With `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`, that can be abbreviated to:

   ```
   sudo dd if=masi.img | pee "dd of=/dev/disk"{2..4}
   ```

   Or even, (if there's no need for `dd`'s useful functions):

   ```
   sudo pee "dd of=/dev/disk"{2..4} < masi.img
   ```

   `pee` is useful; if required one may include, (within each quoted argument), additional distinct `dd` options, and even other pipes and filters, individually tailored to each output device.

With either method the number of output disks can be extended indefinitely.

Comment: Using dd for this isn't necessary. A lot of people believe it's necessary because its usage, specific to copying to or from disk images, is "fossilized" in tutorials written back in the 90s and copied by people who didn't know why. It was used back then to work around a glitch in cp.

Comment: @Random832 It is necessary because it is more stable than `cp`. Try many formats and different allocation sizes. I have not found enough stable `cp` for the work. Please, correct me as an answer here if you can argumentate how `cp` is enough stable.

Comment: @Masi It is _rarely_ necessary to explicitly select a format (what do you even mean by "format") and allocation size (you mean the block size?) for the common purpose of writing a disk image to a disk or reading a disk into a disk image. The reason dd became commonly used for this purpose was because of a bug in cp (GNU cp on Linux specifically) in the early 90s that caused it to skip copying blocks that were all-zero-bytes.

Comment: Bug in `cp` in the 90s? `dd` is 20 years older than that. The main reason for using `dd` was that many devices, especially tape drives, needed to be read/written in fixed block sizes, which is why `dd` has `bs`, `ibs` and `obs` parameters, and it was the only program that could ensure correct block sizes.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I support your argument. I think `dd` is still the only program that can ensure correct block size and provide arguments which you pointed out. All my `cp` attempts have failed eventually. `dd` is solid.

Comment: Why on earth are you piping `pee` into `dd`? Why would you not simply run `tee`?

Comment: @Gilles, here **tee** is indeed preferable to **pee**, (but **dcfldd** is best).    Still, **pee** is useful; one may, if required, include, (within each quoted argument), additional 'dd' options, and even other pipes and filters, individually tailored to each output device.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Yes but the widespread use of dd for _disk_ images (which do _not_ need to be written in fixed block sizes, particularly to a non-raw-mode device) is due to a bug in GNU cp on Linux in the early days _of Linux_. There's information about it in the early Linux mailing list archives.

Comment: @Gilles [And `pee` is likely to be much faster than `tee` as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555344/378966)

Answer (score 25):

You could try [`dcfldd`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcfldd/)
It's an enhanced version of `gnu dd` and it can output to multiple files or disks at the same time:

```
dcfldd if=masi.img of=/dev/disk2 of=/dev/disk3 of=/dev/disk4
```

Comment: Can you explain your first command. Why pipe only before the last `dd`? How does the location of the pipe change with four `dd`?

Comment: `dcfldd` is the fastest, maybe that should be the first choice.

Comment: I found this to be significantly faster than the other piping methods.

Answer (score 3):

Also this is possible with `tee` and `process substitution`:

`dd if=/dev/sda | tee >(dd of=/dev/sdb) >(dd of=/dev/sdc) | dd of=/dev/sdd`

Comment: Can you explain process substitute? How is your answer different from agc's one?

Comment: yeah sure: `process substitution` is used when you need to pipe the stdout of one command to multiple commands. Using a simple pipe will let you pipe to just one command. My answer is achieving the same result as agc's, but in a different way :) Also I never used `pee` before, as I have the `tee` command on my system.

Answer (score 1):

simple way:

`$ sudo dd if=/dev/sd? | tee img.1 > img2`

or

`$ sudo dd if=/dev/sd? | tee img.1 img.2 img.N-1 > img.N`

on specific case:

`dd if=file.img bs=1M | sudo tee /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2 > /dev/null`