# How do I ensure all data to an SSH pipe is sent, despite lengthy disconnects?

Tags: ssh, buffer, persistence

I'm on a laptop with intermittent internet connectivity. (i.e. I sometimes don't have network for a week.)  I want the output of a process on my laptop to end up on my server.  It *all* needs to get there, *eventually*, through SSH, and without me having to think about it.

How can I do this?

---

### Test-case

```sh
# print current date to FIFO every second
while true; do sleep 1; date; done > magic-fifo
```

Leave that running, disconnect from the internet for a week (or sufficiently long to be convincing), then reconnect. All data should be sent immediately while connected, but buffered until reconnection whenever not.

### An attempt

```sh
mkfifo magic-fifo

cat magic-fifo \
| pv --buffer-size 1g --buffer-percent \
| AUTOSSH_POLL=10 AUTOSSH_PORT=50000 autossh user 'cat >> log'
```

[`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) is just here to buffer up to 1 GiB of data, in case a week's data [fills the kernel pipe buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer).

[`autossh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) wraps `ssh` and keeps it running by killing/resurrecting it if the network is down.

This *drops some data at disconnect*, but works otherwise.  I presume the reason for data loss is that `ssh` reads it, realises it cannot send it, then gets killed by `autossh`.

---

I don't necessarily expect the data to persist across reboots, though that would be a nice bonus.

Comment: Have a look at screen an at Mosh.

Comment: @sebix I've used both. They're useful for interactive `ssh` shell sessions, but to my understanding, they don't help when piping data through `ssh` as here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save output to local file, then `rsync --partial --append` on that file to keep pushing it up to the server?