# Limit in saving program output to file in Linux

Tags: shell, terminal, io-redirection, io, output

I know I can use:

```
$ my_program > output.txt
```

To redirect the output to a file, but the problem I have is that when the file reaches 64 `Kb` no more is written in the file and I lose all information that comes next...

What can I do?

Comment: I can not reproduce such a problem in my systems. Please provide more details. What OS, which shell, connected via ssh?.

Comment: @Arrow What OS?: CentOS release 6.8 (Final), Which shell?: -bash, connected via ssh? I tried both via SSH and directly in the machine.

Comment: Run under strace, and see where an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `ulimit -f`. You may be limited by the current file limit value. If so, you can remove your limit by running `ulimit -f unlimited`.

Comment: Well, the output was `unlimited`, this is weird...

Answer (score 0):

The shell use some internal limits. In bash (the shell you are using) the command `ulimit` is used to list them (-a for all):

```
$ ulimit -a
```

However, even if the "pipe size" is set --both the limit for a redirect (`>`) or a pipe (`|`)-- to a low value, 8 (-p) in this linux system, the size of the stream that could be sent over a pipe may be quite big (more than 10 million bytes):

```
$ printf '%0*d' 11000111 0 | wc -c
11000111
```

The other limit, and the real one that apply to a pipe, is read from:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size
65536
```

And set in the same file:

```
$ sudo echo $((4 * 1024)) > /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size
```

However, even a quite small value as set above does not limit an stream in a pipe. The command above with more than 10 million bytes still works.
The reason is that the limit is applied to what *one* block could transfer.

You need a tool like this [script that mix perl and bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/232326) to get writes of *one* block.

```
$ ./pipesize 128 1
write size:        128; bytes successfully before error: 4096
```

That shows the real limit for a pipe (the same limit as in a redirect).