# Piping commands with very large output

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I want to `tar` a directory and write the result to `stdout`, then pipe it to a compression program, like this:

```
tar -cvf - /tmp/source-dir | lzip -o /media/my-usb/result.lz -
```

I have been using pipe all the time with commands which output several lines of text. Now I am wondering what would happen when I pipes a (fast) command with very large output such as `tar` and a very slow compression command followed? Will `tar` wait for its output to be consumed by `lzip`? Or it just does as fast as it can then outputs everything to RAM? It will be a disaster in low RAM system if the latter is true.

Comment: For what it's worth, compression operations like `lzip` on a stream of data are *much faster* than file-system operations  like `tar`.  Unless you have an ancient UNIX box based on an early Sparc or Motorola 68020 chip.

Comment: @O. Jones:  I doubt xz at maximum compression would be faster than an SSD.

Comment: @O.Jones If you compress with maximum option values possible (e.g: `lzip -s256MiB -m273`) it shall take a very long time.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When the data producer (`tar`) tries to write to the pipe too quickly for the consumer (`lzip`) to have time to read all of it, it will *block* until `lzip` has had time to read what `tar` is writing.  There is a small buffer associated with the pipe, but its size is likely to be smaller than the size of most `tar` archives.  There is no risk of filling up your system's RAM with your pipeline.

"Blocking" simply means that when `tar` does a call to the `write()` library function (or equivalent), the call won't return until the data has been delivered to the pipe buffer, which could take a bit of time if `lzip` is slow to read from that same buffer.  You should be able to see this in `top` where `tar` would slow down and sleep a lot compared to `lzip` (assuming `tar` is in fact quicker than `lzip`).

You would therefore *not* fill up a significant amount of RAM with your pipeline.  To do that (if you wanted to), you could use something like `pv` in the middle, with some large buffer (here, a gigabyte):

```
tar -cvf - /tmp/source-dir | pv --buffer-size 1G | lzip -o /media/my-usb/result.lz -
```

This would still block `tar` whenever `pv` blocks.  `pv` would block when its buffer is full and it can't write to `lzip`.

---

The reverse situation works in a similar way, i.e. if you have a slow left-hand side of a pipe writing to a fast right-hand side, the consumer on the right would block on `read()` until there is data to be read from the pipe.

This (data I/O) is the only thing that synchronises the processes taking part in a pipeline. Apart from reading and writing (and occasionally blocking while waiting for someone else to read or write), they would run independently of each other.

Comment: FWIW, the size of the pipe buffer is dependent on OS and versions.  Real old Linux had buffers around 4Kb in size.  Later it defaulted to something like 64Kb, and provides a `fcntl()` where an open pipe buffer can be resized (eg to 1M) as required.

Comment: From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer  "PIPE_BUF" is the largest value that can be written _atomically_.    `sysctl fs.pipe-user-pages-soft` returns 16384 on my machine, and `sysctl fs.pipe-max-size` returns 1048576

Comment: All that adding buffer here really will do is just increase the memory usage of the pipeline. Except in a few pathological cases, there's usually little to gain by adding large buffers between commands in a pipeline.

Comment: @LieRyan This is absolutely true. In this case it's a useless addition. It would be more useful it was, for example, part of a pipeline stage that received data on a remote system ( `... | ssh user@host 'pv --buffer-size 1G | lzip ...'` or something similar), or if `pv` or some other utility was used to throttle the data stream in some way.

Comment: @LieRyan I didn't know about `pv`, but use cases which come to mind for a large buffer are reading from a time-metered connection or from a USB stick you want to remove as soon as possible, or generally from any process which locks a critical resource.

Comment: Piping from a network into an I/O-bound process that does writes in chunks is another place where it comes in handy. Several jobs ago (so the details are hazy), I had a job that effectively did periodic flushes to disk, hanging for a significant while as they were ongoing; without `pv` and a large buffer, this stopped the download, meaning a substantial loss in throughput. Sure, if your I/O system flushes at a reasonably steady rate, it doesn't make much of a difference; but that's not always the case.

Comment: @LieRyan: you could also imagine cases where the command you're piping into can usually or nearly keep up with the disk, but processing rate varies with data.  e.g. simple repeating patterns compress quickly; redundancy over a longer distance and/or varying in pattern takes longer to find.  64kiB is probably too small and would lead to stalls in the pipeline.  A few MiB is very reasonable a lot of the time, but yeah usually 1GiB would be overkill for most jobs and just lead to more cache and TLB thrashing.

Answer (score 2):

GNU **tar** has **--lzip** option to **"filter the archive through lzip**", so you may want to use instead:

```
tar -cvf --lzip /media/my-usb/result.lz /tmp/source-dir
```

Answering the question: in your case the system will manage the pipe properly using default system buffer size.

Comment: I think that the questioner wants to know what "properly" actually entails.

Comment: All the compression and decompression options in tar just fork an appropriate sub-process and connect it internally to stdout (to write an archive) or stdin (to read an archive). The underlying mechanism is identical to the shell's pipework.

Comment: I know the `--lzip` option of `tar`, but it lack the flexibility of setting options for `lzip` itself. By piping commands, I can throw in a lot of options for `lzip`.

Comment: Doesn't just assume GNU, but assumes *recent* GNU. Why write code that reduces your portability unless you get some kind of benefit in return?