# Does cat use lazy evaluation?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cat

When using pipes for example

```
sudo cat /dev/sda | strings | less
```

I can move around the lines of strings of my sda device. But are the contents of the sda device loaded fully and outputed to the output stream of cat? Or are the new lines evaluated whenever a program requests output from cat ? ( i.e. i press j on the less pager)

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: "But are the contents of the sda device loaded fully and outputed to the output stream of cat?" No. Just like `yes hallo baby | less` does not first load the _infinite_ output of `yes` before piping it to `less`. This strange notion of commands in a pipeline being run sequentially certainly has its origin in some lousy textbook or tutorial, I don't think that so many people fell in the same trap by themselves.

Comment: @mosvy That's exactly how DOS cmd in Win 3.1 and 3.11 implemented pipes: a temporary file between each pair of programs, run separately. It also implemented the NUL device in every folder, but it could only be used by one stream at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `cat` and `strings`, and most similar utilities¹, read a little bit of input at a time, process it, then read more input, and so on. So in your case, `cat` only reads what `less` displays, plus a little more that's in transit.

In more detail, the basic operation of `cat` is:

- Reserve a few kilobytes of memory for use as a buffer.
- While there's more input available:

  - Read up to N bytes of input into the buffer. (This overwrites data that was written out in a previous cycle.)
  - Write the buffer content to the output.

The write operation blocks until there's a place to copy the output. When the output of a pipe, the pipe itself consumes a little memory in the kernel, which is called the [pipe buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer). Once that's full, if `cat` tries to write to the pipe, the write attempt blocks until there's room. There can be room in the pipe buffer when the process on the read end of the pipe reads some data.

The `strings` program works in the same way as `cat`, except that it doesn't copy its whole input, only selected parts.

The `less` program works a bit differently: it keeps everything that it's read in memory. It doesn't recycle its buffer, it keeps growing it as long as more input keeps coming in. The read part is similar, however, in that `less` only reads data when it needs it: it only reads up to the last line that it displays, plus a little more that it reads in anticipation if available.

So when you run `sudo cat /dev/sda | strings | less`, what's been read from `/dev/sda` consists of:

- Data that `less` has already displayed (or scrolled past).
- Up to a few kB of data that `less` has read but not yet displayed.
- Up to a few kB in the pipe buffer between `strings` and `less`.
- Up to a few kB in the memory of `strings`.
- Up to a few kB in the pipe buffer between `cat` and `strings`.
- Up to a few kB in the memory of `cat`.

You can watch when each program reads and writes data by tracing its system calls:

```
sudo strace -e read,write -o cat.strace cat /dev/sda | strace -e read,write -o cat.strace strings | strace -e read,write -o less.strace less
```

and watch the `*.strace` files. You can also check how much `cat` has read by checking the file offset, for example with `lsof -p1234` or with `head /proc/1234/fdinfo/0` where `1234` is the process ID of `cat`.

¹  <sub>Among the basic text processing utility, the main exception is `sort`, which can't emit any output until it's read the whole input: for all it knows, the first line of output may well be the last line of input that it reaches.</sub>

Comment: Thanks that was very insightful about the details of cat and pipes! Also I haven't heard about the strace command and I'm excited to test it !

Answer (score 5):

This has more to do with how `less` works than with how `cat` or `strings` work.

The `cat` command will only push data to its standard output, and it will block whenever the pipe buffer between it and `strings` is full and nobody is reading.  `cat` does minimal buffering by itself, and the pipe buffer is typically small.

This is also  true for `strings`.  It will process the data from `cat` and will block when `less` is not reading the data that `strings` produces.

`less` will buffer its input to allow you to move back and forth in the data that it displays.  When you scroll to the next page, `less` will read more data from `strings` into its buffer. While you are not scrolling forward, I believe `less` will only read a limited amount of data (and hence `strings` and `cat` will be blocked while you are not scrolling forward).

If you pipe a large amount of data to `less`, quite a lot of memory will be used for this buffering *if* you decide to read it all to the end with `less`.

There is an option, `-B`, that limits the amount of memory used for buffering to 64 kilobytes (or however much you specify with the `-b` option).  Limiting the buffer size in this way will prevent you from scrolling back more than what can be stored in the specified buffer space, but will also allow you to read huge amounts of data with `less` without running out of memory.

See also `man less` on your system.

Comment: Thanks I think I have a better understanding of pipes now and your explanation of what less does is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Pipes have limited buffer space, and if a pipe reader (such as `less` in your example) does not read more data from the pipe, the writer will be blocked after filling the buffer. This will affect the `strings` command, which in turn will block the `cat` command after its pipe is full.

Naturally, the `cat` command cannot read the whole sda device contents into main memory, so if blocks that haven't been read by it yet are being changed, `cat` will see the changed contents.

Answer (score 2):

On some systems (e.g. MS-Dos) the pipe is implemented by copying the output of the first command to a file, then running the 2nd command to read from this file.
**Unix does not do it that way**.

On Unixes it is like a production line. Each stage works simultaneously, reading input and producing output. If process A produces faster than process B consumes, then there is a build up of stock between process A and B. When this is too much (½KiB to 4 KiB), process A is paused. When there is no stock for B to process, then B is paused. Processes are paused and un-paused, to keep stock levels low.

The code in these programs does not care about any of this. It just reads input and writes output. If it tries to read, before data is available, or tries to write before the next process is ready, then the operating system, will pause it, until ready.

When there is no more to read (and nothing more is on its way), the reader gets an end-of-file, and will exit. This in turn triggers an end-of-file in the next process.

Comment: That's really interesting! Is it in anyway better to store pipes as files and do buffers have drawbacks ?  Is this still implemented this way in modern Windows systems?

Comment: The only advantage of the file approach is that you can do it on a system that can only run one program at a time. Disadvantages are that you have to wait for the fist program to finish before the 2nd starts .... and the last to start, before there is any output. Modern (time does not flow the same for all) OSes can run more than one program at a time, so the pipe is better.