# Trap SIGPIPE upon writing to FIFO

Tags: signals, fifo, trap

These are the steps to reproduce the problem.

**`writer`**:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo NoReader!' PIPE
cat > fifo
```

Open two terminals.
I will denote them by the `>T1<` and `>T2<` headers below,
and their prompts by `$`.

```
>T1<
$ mkfifo fifo
$ bash writer
ABC
>T2<
$ cat fifo
ABC
^C
>T1<
DEF
$ echo $?
141
```

From [`man fifo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html),

> When a process tries to write to a FIFO that is not opened for
> read on the other side, the process is sent a SIGPIPE signal.

At the time I enter `DEF`, the FIFO has no reader anymore. So
I expected the trap on SIGPIPE to be triggered after entering `DEF` and the corresponding `NoReader!`
message. Instead, the process silently terminates. The error code is [141, which
indicates that it was terminated indeed by SIGPIPE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

On the other hand, executing this **`newWriter`**

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo NoReader!' PIPE
var=$(head -c 100000 /dev/urandom)
echo "$var" > fifo
```

in terminal 1 and `head -c 1 fifo` in terminal 2 does trigger the trap! However, if I just extract 1000 bytes from urandom instead of 100000, the trap is not triggered.

What am I missing? Why wasn't the trap triggered in the first `writer` example, but was in the `newWriter` with 100000 bytes (and not with 1000 bytes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### cat

The reason why the `bash` trap handler is not executed is simply the fact that `bash` does not receive that signal. It is sent to the writing process only which is `cat`.

The trap handler is executed if it is the shell itself which does the write:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>fifo
trap 'echo NoReader!' PIPE
while IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 input; do
    printf %s "$input" >&3 || break
done </dev/urandom
```

### head

`strace` shows the reason for the different behaviour of the `head` calls: The FIFO buffers 4096 bytes (on my system; somehow this value can be retrieved from the kernel). So you should not get an error with `-c 4096` but with `4097`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It may be helpful to add [How big is the pipe buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11946). I found that the buffer was 65536 B in size and confirmed what you said. Also may be helpful to add that `newWriter`'s trap was triggered because what was used to write to the FIFO was `echo`, a **shell builtin**, so the shell caught the signal.